# Why did the latest data value result returned from "order by time desc", "limit 10", "limit 100" are different in Apache IoTDB?

Tags: time-series, apache-iotdb, iotdb

I am now using version 1.1.0 of Apache IoTDB, and when I am executing `order by time desc`, `order by time desc limit 10`, and `order by time desc limit 100`,  the latest query results of the time series are different (it should not be like this). When I add `limit 10` to the query statement, the first data returned is not the timestamp of the latest data results stored in IoTDB. Is there a bug for this function and how to correct it?

Answer (score -1):

This bug should already been fixed in new Apache IoTDB versions(for example Version 1.2 and 1.3), so you can update your IoTDB to either versions to solve this error.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, this is a [known bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IOTDB-5717) in Apache IoTDB `1.1` that [got fixed](https://github.com/apache/iotdb/pull/9435) in `1.2`. You basically need to upgrade your IoTDB instance.